# Magento 2: What's the `Magento` in a Static Asset URL?

Tags: magento2, view, static-content

In Magento 2, a static asset URL from a module looks like this

```
http://example.magento.com/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Pulsestorm_FrontendTutorial1/hello.js
```

What's the `Magento` for between the area and theme? (`frontend/Magento/blank`).  Is this hardcoded somewhere to Magento? Is it a name that's configurable per "Magento Application".  Something else?

i.e. I know this is where Magento ends up generating the static asset files for the product, but what does this part of the URL represent, and where is Magento's core code pulling it from?

Comment: Great question. I personally don't like having the module names in the asset paths either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you create your theme inside app/design/yourVendor/Youtheme and activated your theme the assets url will be change to :
 http://example.magento.com/static/frontend/yourVendor/Youtheme/en_US/Pulsestorm_FrontendTutorial1/hello.js
Magento create hello.js for every theme already declared inside registration.php , Magento equal yourVendor (almost interface for m1)
ok if you go to table theme in db you will find theme_path yourVendor/Youtheme
the model related is Magento\Theme\Model\Theme

Magento for  Getting a static view file name, using fallback mechanism passed as parameters:

```
getFile($area, ThemeInterface $themeModel, $locale, $file, $module = null)
```

is ThemeInterface $themeModel

for assets as your case all big players i find inside vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset as example the intern system use (vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/File.php):

```
public function getPath()
{
    $result = '';
    $result = $this->join($result, $this->context->getPath());
    $result = $this->join($result, $this->module);
    $result = $this->join($result, $this->filePath);
    $result = $this->minification->addMinifiedSign($result);
    return $result;
}
```

in the beta version the blank it's simple to view it's located inside app/design/Magento/blank but in rc all is stocked inside vendor for blank is : vandor/magento/theme-frontend-blank like modules and framwork ..

Comment: So to clarify, Magento is the vendor of the theme, whereas Pulsestorm etc is the vendor of the module?

Comment: @RobbieAverill That's right -- `Pulsestorm_FrontendTutorial1` is the **module** name.  The full theme name is `Magento/blank` -- with `Magento` being the theme's vendor, and `blank` being the theme's name.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html) **Magento** is Vendor Name (for Magento_blank theme).